# When do redstone torches burn out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I know that if I make a redstone circuit that switches too often, my redstone torches will 'burn out' and stop working. Under what circumstances does this happen? Will a slow circuit eventually burn out? If not, what's the maximum 'clock speed' for a circuit such that it will *never* burn out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest clock that will not burn out is the 4-clock. A common design is this one:

```
- =wire
r =repeater

- r -
r   r
- r -
```

I think all repeaters must be set to 4 to remain stable, but I've been fine setting them to 3 before.

**Edit:** I did some research, to investigate. I have found that a torch needs at least 8 ticks total delay between pulses to prevent burnout. So the repeater clock with 4 repeaters should be set to at least 2 ticks each.

My basic setup:
[image: My experiment setup]

Basically, my experiment involved that basic repeater clock hooked up to 4 torches. I started with them each at 1 tick delay, and, as expected, all of the torches burnt out very quickly. I increased the delay on the repeaters one by one until the torches stopped burning out. This point came when each repeater was at 2 ticks delay (though the torches were probably pulsing too quickly for most devices).

Though it should be noted that torches can be *extremely* buggy sometimes; sometimes, pulling a lever will burn a torch out...

Comment: But wouldn't a piston clock going faster than the 4-clock cause other circuitry to burn out?

Comment: That is true. If you have it hooked up to other torches, then 4 is the number to shoot for (though a lot of times, I try to adapt my circuitry so I don't have to deal with it)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the research you did? This is shaping up to be a great answer, but it needs to be perfect before I'll accept it :-P

Answer (score -5):

A redstone torch will simply "blow out" when its state is being changed too quickly (i.e. a very fast clock).

Comment: I know this, but *exactly* how quickly is too quickly?

Comment: The question asker probably already knows this, considering that is in the first sentence of his question and all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not pay enough attention to the question.

Comment: Maybe you should delete this answer.